# RealmSwiftのデータを全て消去したい

Tags: realm

RealmSwiftを使ってデータベースアプリを作っております。
コーディングの途中でプロパティ名の変更をしたため、マイグレーション処理が必要となりました。
その際、ビルドはできてもシミュレーターを動かすと途中で落ちるようになってしまいました。
そこで、まだ開発途中なので、一旦RealmSwiftの全てのデータを消去したいと思います。
Realmブラウザを使う方法や、Xcodeからそのデータの場所を特定する方法があるようです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

シミュレータ、またはデバイスから開発中のアプリケーションを削除すればファイルも一緒に消えます。
その後再インストールすればいいです。

Comment: ご指導有難うございます。
やってみます。